# send ajax request after successfull validation using jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery plugin validation for form validation I have a simple question which I couldn't figure out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contactForm").validate({
        rules: {
            contactName: "Please Enter Full Name",
            contactBody: "Please Enter full message here",
            contactEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This validates perfect, what I need is if it is successful than send ajax request or mail to the user otherwise don't.

I know how to send mail using jquery but I need to send it on successful, how ? even I am unable to use alert it gives me bracket } missing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could intercept the submit by using the **submitHandler** option.  This option can be set to a callback function that could fire off an ajax request that sends an email.

To make this work, you will need to setup a script on the server that handles the mail sending.  Send all of the data required in the ajax request and the server script can send the mail and return a success response.

Comment: how i will use submithandler ?

Comment: You would send it with the parameter object for validate(), as in validate( {rules:[your rules here], submitHandler: function() { ajaxRequest(); } }); or something like that

Comment: <pre>$().ready(function() {

 $("#contactForm").validate({
 rules: {
   contactName: "Please Enter Full Name",
   contactBody: "Please Enter full message here",
 contactEmail: {
    required: true,
    email: true
   },
   submitHandler: function() { }; 
 
  } 
 
 });
});</pre>Error:missing }after:(